# How to secure JSONP requests with Web API?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I am using the custom JSONP formatter from here:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Apr/02/Creating-a-JSONP-Formatter-for-ASPNET-Web-API

It works great with the latest Web API. However, how do I limit so it is not available for ALL my Web API service, but only the ones I put a JSONP attribute or something. Any idea on how to secure this to only certain actions I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of actions, if you can think along the lines of the type of the objects that you want to return as JSONP, you can change the formatter like this to allow only certain types to be serialized as JSONP.

```
public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
{
    // Check type here and return true only for the types you want to allow JSONP
    return true;
}
```

If type based filtering is not possible, another option will be to not add the formatter to the formatters collection and explicitly specify `JsonpFormatter`, like this, only in the action methods that you want to return JSONP.

```
return new HttpResponseMessage()
{
    Content = new ObjectContent<MyType>(anInstanceOfMyType, new JsonpFormatter())
};
```

One downside however is this will return only JSONP regardless of what conneg comes up with.